# Codeigniter Forms Issue

Tags: forms, codeigniter

i'm very new to CI, so here's a simple question:
I want to create 3 forms on the same line. Why is the following code creates first form on the first row, second one on the second row and third one on the third row?
Thanks!

```
<?php echo form_open('tuti');
echo form_submit('home_b','home_button');
echo form_close();?>


<?php echo form_open('tuti2');
echo form_submit('create_b','create_button');
echo form_close();?>


<?php echo form_open('tuti3');
echo form_submit('login_b','login_button');
echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: If I am understanding you right, this isn't a CodeIgniter problem, as the form is been created. This is a front-end issue. Do you have any HTML or CSS?

Comment: use a table or css layout

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<table>
       <tr>
       <td>
          <?php echo form_open('tuti');
          echo form_submit('home_b','home_button');
          echo form_close();?>
       </td>
       <td>
          <?php echo form_open('tuti2');
          echo form_submit('create_b','create_button');
          echo form_close();?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo form_open('tuti3');
          echo form_submit('login_b','login_button');
          echo form_close();?>
         </td>
    </table>
```

ps: Also you can use Bootstrap buttons. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups